# How to query objects by entity when more than 1 entity derive from a common entity and saved in the same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, tph

Let's say I have a parent class with 2 sub-classes, with the following configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ParentType>(entity =>
{
   entity.HasDiscriminator()
         .HasValue<ChildA>("ChildA")
         .HasValue<ChildB>("ChildB");
}
```

So how do I pull the data based on the child type?

```
var result = context.ParentTypes.
                    .Where(x => ...);
```

In the table, I see a column called `Discriminator` with values, such as `ChildA` and `ChildB`. However, there's no such property on `x.Discriminator`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing queries against a TPH (Table per Hierarchy) Entity Framework configuration, you can use the `OfType<T>` LinQ method to filter the types. This also lets you access the properties in that derived class. For example if we had a `ChildA` class like this:

```
public class ChildA : ParentType
{
    public string FavouriteFood { get; set; }
}
```

We could query like this:

```
var childAWhoLikeCheese = context.ParentTypes
    .OfType<ChildA>()
    .Where(x => x.FavouriteFood == "Cheese");
```

This will actually create a query something like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ParentTypes
WHERE Discriminator = "ChildA"
AND FavouriteFood = "Cheese"
```